# Understanding WordPress Customizer JS API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jsapi

I have been trying to educate myself to create new panels sections and controls dynamically using the WordPress customizer's JS API.

It has been frustrating and I was unable to get the exact way to achieve this via JS API.

So far, this is some thing I am doing to make it happen but with no success:

```
// for Settings
api.create( 
    params.id, 
    params.id, 
    params.default, 
    params.args 
);

// for controls
var controlConstructor = api.controlConstructor[controlparams.type];
var control = new controlConstructor(controlparams.id, {
    params: controlparams,
    previewer: api.previewer
});
api.control.add( 
    controlparams.id, 
    control 
);

 //for Sections
 var section = new api.Section(sectionparams.id, { 
    params: sectionparams
 }); 
api.section.add( sectionparams.id, section );
api.section(sectionparams.id).activate();
```

None of them seem to work as the section doesn't appear and I have to run `wp.customize.section(sectionparams.id).activate()` twice in console to make the section appear, the same is with control.

Comment: What API are you using? I was trying to read up the [official wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API#Adding_a_New_Section), but did not find anything. What is the `api` object?

Comment: `api` is the `wp.customize` object. I'd like know how to render customizer assets (panels, sections, controls and settings) via its javascript api.

Comment: I would like to answer your questions about WordPress Customize API, but your original question lacks some details, `controlparams` and `sectionparams` in particular. Also, giving away some server-side code for review would be nice. (I believe I can help you because I've learnt some WP Customize API karate and stuff.)

Comment: This post explains it perfectly: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/305959/14008

Answer (score 2):

Read the [documentation about the JS API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/#javascriptunderscore-js-rendered-custom-controls)

You also can find [advanced examples in this plugin](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-posts/tree/master/js)

Comment: JS API doc doesn't look much helpful in this case. :(

Answer (score -4):

Adding Sections and settings to your theme is done in the functions.php file where you can add new settings and sections.

The JavaScript part that you are attempting to use is only used for the LIVE Preview section, when you are actually changing theme settings.

Comment: You're talking about PHP API which is I am well aware about. The question here is regarding JS API which makes the use of `wp.customize` JS object.

Comment: When you say you have to run `api.section(sectionparams.id).activate()` 2x do you mean the first time when the page loads and then manually in the console or just 2x in the console?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your code in an anoymous function like it shows in the example? Also, why are you using `api` instead of `wp.customize`

`(function($){
    //Code Here
})(jQuery);`

Comment: Yeah, I did. In my code it is done like this `(function($,api){ //Code Here })(jQuery, wp.customize);` hence the `api`. :)